# Invalid bind address format: Connect to remote DOCKER_HOST via ssh from docker in docker

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-in-docker

I am trying to use a remote `DOCKER_HOST` via `ssh` from a docker-in-docker container, like this:

```sh
docker run --rm \
  -e DOCKER_HOST=ssh://<USER>@<HOST> \
  docker:18.06 \
  docker ps
```

But this returns an error:

> Invalid bind address format: ssh://<USER>@<HOST>

If I am not using the docker-in-docker container, it works.

Is it possible to use a remote `DOCKER_HOST` via `ssh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Engine 18.09 added support for `$DOCKER_HOST` over ssh.  From [the Docker 18.09.0 release notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/18.09/#new-features):

> Added support for remote connections using SSH [docker/cli#1014](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1014)

Since you're specifying an older `docker:18.06` image, it doesn't have this support.